# Where can I find the select module imported by Python 2.7's multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-import, python-multiprocessing

I successfully built (from source) *Python 2.7* for *UnixWare 7.*

However, when I try to import the `multiprocessing` module, I get this:

[image: import error]

I searched for `select.py` in all the relevant (I hope) Python directories, but did not find it:

[image: find results]

### Can you suggest where can I find the particular `select.py` that `subprocess.py` wants to import?

**Edit 1:**
`select.so` does not exist in the Python library on *UnixWare 7:*
[image: Select.so does not exist]

Comment: Likely `select` is loaded from a shared library.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: there is no `select.py`. It is a builtin module, compiled from selectmodule.c

Comment: Thanks, @Antti. I'll look for `selectmodule.c` and see if I can compile it under UnixWare 7.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `select` module is available only for Linux and BSD (and thus not for UnixWare) while `multiprocessing` module tries to `import select` when it is run not on Windows.

Comment: Any suggestions how to get out of this catch-22 situation - before I'm forced to muck around with the sources?

Comment: @boardrider I wouldn't know if the multiprocessing would work anyhow.

Comment: `UnixWare` is *just another Unix*. Are you sure `select` is not available on it? I'd have thought it'd be available on any POSIX compliant system.

Comment: Do you know what is `select's` location, @Martijn, on other Unixes?

Comment: @boardrider: On Mac it is located in `lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so`.

Comment: @boardrider: however, it can also be compiled as part of the `python` binary itself.

Comment: @boardrider: See the [`Setup.dist` file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/Setup.dist#l198), which states that *If you have a really backward UNIX, select and socket may not be supported...*..

Comment: Thanks for the idea to incorporate `selectmodule.c` into python itself, @Martijn. I guess I have to do some reading to figure out how to do that.